# Possible to load ASCX with jQuery.load() function?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, jquery, ascx

Is it possible without encapsulating these controls in aspx files? The Register tag makes me think that it is not.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call ascx page directly, they can't serve any html without added to aspx or render then dynamically in response to any page/handler.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way would be to have a generic aspx stub page that acts as a host to the ascx in the normal web forms way make a callback to the that page using JQuery's $.ajax() method with some arguments to denote what ascx control you want to load.

Then on your stub / host page, override the render method and render the control directly to the output stream using response.output.write. The callback handler on the client will catch the output and then it can be inserted into the DOM in the normal way or using using the version of $.load() that allows the specification of a DOM element.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to [load ASCX controls through jQuery, using an ASMX service that creates a Page instance to render the user control](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/).

Answer (score 0):

Since I've started using jQuery/Ajax more and more, I find I've been using server controls less and less.

Things that I used to put into controls are now just individual aspx pages which get loaded into panels.

If you have old ASCX files, it shouldn't be too hard to convert them to ASPX

Answer (score 0):

No.

That said, you could place your ascx inside an UpdatePanel and set the panel's content visible/invisible using the standard Asp.Net postback mechanisms.

Or you could write a separate IHttpHandler which generates HTML code that your Javascript code adds to the page using DOM. This part of the page would however not be accessible in PostBack.

Answer (score -1):

No, ASCX are user-controls, that exist on ASPX. You will need to make it a Page, or convert into Handler.