# Load ascx via jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms

Is there a way to load ascx file by jQuery?

**UPDATE**:

thanks to @Emmett and @Yads. I'm using a handler with the following jQuery ajax code:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",  //GET
    url: "Foo.ashx",
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response)
    {
        jQuery('#controlload').append(response.d); // or response
    },
    error: function ()
    {
        jQuery('#controlload').append('error');
    }
 });
```

but I get an error. Is my code wrong?

Another **Update** : 
I am using

```
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
{
    jQuery('#controlload').append(thrownError);
}
```

and this is what i get :

> Invalid JSON:
>   Test  =>(this test is label inside my ascx)

and my ascx file after Error!!!

Another **Update** :

my ascx file is somthing like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server">Test</asp:Label>
```

but when calling ajax i get this error in asp: :(

> Control 'ctl00_ddl' of type 'DropDownList' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

thanks to @Yads. but his solution only work with html tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212639/possible-to-load-ascx-with-jquery-load-function

Comment: is it impossible? is there any way convert ascx file to aspx? or better way?

Comment: the error function can take a request object, examine the request.responseText to find out what the error is.

Comment: @Raika Your dataType in your request needs to be 'html' not 'json', btw you need to use the @ tag if you want to notify someone

Comment: @Yads. I'm new to jquery. can you update your answer with jquery? thnaks.... :P

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, why not use an UpdatePanel and let asp.net do it for you? The solutions described will give you a way to wrap the output of a usercontrol and render the html, but it will have no context, so it might as well just be HTML.

Comment: By the way, see my similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045509/updating-asp-net-server-rendered-controls-using-ajax ... the 2nd answer has another interesting approach if you really need to do something like this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Building off Emmett's solution

```
public class FooHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        context.Response.Write(RenderPartialToString("Foo.ascx"));
    }

    private string RenderPartialToString(string controlName)
    {
        Page page = new Page();
        Control control = page.LoadControl(controlName);
        page.Controls.Add(control);

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);

        return writer.ToString();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Use the following jquery request

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",  //GET
    url: "Foo.ashx",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response)
    {
        jQuery('#controlload').append(response); // or response
    },
    error: function ()
    {
        jQuery('#controlload').append('error');
    }
 });
```

Comment: @Raika Yes just go Add->New Item->Generic Handler

Comment: @Raika no worries. I'm also assuming emmett's solution works :-)

Comment: @Yads. thanks. I'm update question. please help me with this too.

Comment: @Raika, try the included ajax call.

Comment: @Raika, try the updated RenderPartialToString, if that doesn't work. You may be SOL if you want to keep using server controls in your ascx. If you want to switch your ascx to either html, or using server tags you should be fine.

Comment: i,m getting Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.UI.Page'. but any way thank for your help and i think is better to work on some other solution instead this.

Comment: @Raika is this finally worked with asp.net controls on an general ascx?

Comment: How do you pass params to RenderPartialToString("Foo.ascx") ?

Answer (score 3):

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return new ContentResult
    {
        Content = RenderPartialToString("Foo.ascx", null),
        ContentType = "text/html"
    };
}

//http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/render-partial-view-to-string-asp-net-mvc-benchmark
public static string RenderPartialToString(string controlName, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
{
    ViewPage vp = new ViewPage();

    vp.ViewData = viewData;

    Control control = vp.LoadControl(controlName);
    vp.Controls.Add(control);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter tw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            vp.RenderControl(tw);
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: @Raika, create an ashx handler that will do the same thing Emmett suggested and instead of a ViewPage object create a Page object. You won't need the ViewDataDictionary either.

Comment: @Raika You can create ashx handlers in WebForms. I just posted a solution.

Answer (score 1):

*.ascx files are rendered on the server side (inside of an *.aspx page), not the client side (where JavaScript is executed).

One option might be to create a blank *.aspx, put the user control on the *.aspx page, and then get that page via jQuery and dump the result on the page.

**Edit**

Based on your comment, I have another suggestion:

If you're developing a CMS style application, you should build your *.ascx controls so that they are [compatible with the ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit](http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/04/01/simplified-asp-net-ajax-custom-control-development.aspx). That will allow the users to add content to the page without doing a full refresh.

If you really want to make things nice for the user, you should check out [Web Parts and ASP.NET AJAX](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mharder/archive/2007/01/23/webparts-and-asp-net-ajax-1-0.aspx) as Web Parts were really designed so that users could customize the content on their pages.

Comment: i'm developing web applicatiob CMS like. i need to call some part of my application as ascx file. i don't want to postback the page. is there a better way to do that? i dont want to load all part too.

Comment: @Raika - If you really want to do things the right way, you'll make your page support ASP.NET WebForms AJAX (UpdatePanel, etc.) and make your controls compatible with that. That would allow you to load things dynamically via AJAX.

Comment: thanks. can you give me more link about web parts or complete tutorial for web parts?

Comment: @Raika - The last link I posted has links to the appropriate pages on MSDN. Unfortunately Web Parts can get fairly complex so you'll have to do a bit of reading.