# can you use jqmodal ajax with web forms

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqmodal

is there a way to use jqmodal's ajax property with asp.net webforms?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Button1').click(function() {
        $('#modalContent').jqm({
            ajax: "~/ShelterCreateForm.ascx"
        });
        $('#modalContent').jqmShow(this);
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jqModal is server side technology agnostic meaning that it can be used with absolutely any language on the server including WebForms in condition that it points to a server side url which returns the partial html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#Button1').click(function() {
            $('#modalContent').jqm({
                ajax: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Foo.ashx") %>'
            });
            $('#modalContent').jqmShow(this);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the server side url that returns this partial (`Foo.ashx`) might be a generic handler as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597103/load-ascx-via-jquery/4597341#4597341):

```
public class FooHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        context.Response.Write(RenderPartialToString("ShelterCreateForm.ascx"));
    }

    private string RenderPartialToString(string controlName)
    {
        var page = new Page();
        var control = page.LoadControl(controlName);
        page.Controls.Add(control);

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, writer, false);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```