# Find runtime loaded user control(ascx) object in the page(aspx)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls, ascx

I am loading dynamics user controls(ascx) to page(aspx) with jquery-ajax. Runtime,
I want to have an instance of user controls that has loaded in Page.
How can I do?
Thanks

```
       function funDersinSubeleriniGoster(programDersGrubDersId) {
            $.blockUI();
            var ControlName = "OgrenciUserControls/KayitYenileme/DersSubeleriControl.ascx";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "KayitYenileme.aspx/DersinSubeleriniYukle",
                data: "{controlName:'" + ControlName + "',programDersGrubDersId:'" + programDersGrubDersId + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    $.unblockUI();
                    //$('#dialogDersKayitPopup').html(response.d).dialog({ resizable: false, height: 600, width: 800, modal: true });
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    $.unblockUI();
                    //$('#dialogDersKayitPopup').html(msg).dialog({ resizable: false, height: 600, width: 800, modal: true });
                }
            });

            return false;

        }
```

aspx Page

```
[WebMethod]
public static void DersinSubeleriniYukle(string controlName, int programDersGrubDersId)
{

}

private void UserControlsFind()
{
    //I want to have user controls instance.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the objects name (controlName in your DersinSubeleriniYukle sub ), you can find the control from the server side:

```
dim myControl as yourUserControlType 
myControl = me.findControl(controlName)
```

You may need to add a reference in your ascx page, like this:

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/user_controls/yourUserControlType.ascx"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer: [Load ascx via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597103/load-ascx-via-jquery)

Also check here: http://zemlyaniy.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/render-ascx-control-to-pure-html-and-load-using-jquery/